# Zxing NotFoundException Java

Tags: java, qr-code, barcode, zxing

I can`t decode some barcodes with Zxing. It scans barcodes only from images like this:

[image].

I need to scan the barcodes in images like this:

[image]

And this is code where I read barcode using Zxing

```
Map<DecodeHintType, Object> hintMap = new EnumMap<DecodeHintType, Object>(
                DecodeHintType.class);
        hintMap.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
        hintMap.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS,
                EnumSet.allOf(BarcodeFormat.class));
        hintMap.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.FALSE);
        try {
            System.out.println("Data read from QR Code: "
                    + readQRCode(filePath, charset, hintMap));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

```
public static String readQRCode(String filePath, String charset, Map hintMap)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NotFoundException {
    BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
            new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(
                    ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(filePath)))));
    Result qrCodeResult = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitmap,
            hintMap);
    return qrCodeResult.getText();
}
```

EDIT:
I found that the second image that I want to decode perfectly decodes using https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx

Comment: You can try to look at [the code of `DecodeServlet`](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/zxingorg/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/web/DecodeServlet.java) which seems to be the backend of the link you post. Check the `processImage` method in there to see what they do differently from you.